# nested for loop for spliting string based on multiple delimiters

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I'm working on a Python assignment which requires a text to be delimited, sorted and printed as:

- sentences are delimited by `.`
- phrases by `,`
- then printed

What I've done so far:

```
text =  "what time of the day is it. i'm heading out to the ball park, with the kids, on this nice evening. are you willing to join me, on the walk to the park, tonight." 


for i, phrase in enumerate(text.split(',')):
   print('phrase #%d: %s' % (i+1,phrase)):


phrase #1: what time of the day is it. i'm heading out to the ball park
phrase #2:  with the kids
phrase #3:  on this nice evening. are you willing to join me
phrase #4:  on the walk to the park
phrase #5:  tonight.
```

I know a nested for loop is needed and have tried with:

```
for s, sentence in enumerate(text.split('.')):
     for p, phrase in enumerate(text.split(',')):
         print('sentence #%d:','phrase #%d: %s' %(s+1,p+1,len(sentence),phrase)) 

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

A hint and/or a simple example would be welcomed.

Comment: The proper pronoun, "I", is spelled "I".  Please use "I" when referring to yourself.  Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code snippet

```
for s, sentence in enumerate(text.split('.')):
     for p, phrase in enumerate(text.split(',')):
         print('sentence #%d:','phrase #%d: %s' %(s+1,p+1,len(sentence),phrase))
```

1. If I understand you correctly, you want to split the sentence by delimited `.`. Then Each of these sentences you want to split on phrases which is again delimited by `,`. So second line of your should actually split the output of the outer loops enumeration. Something like

   ```
   for p, phrase in enumerate(sentence.split(',')):
   ```
2. The Print Statement. If you ever See an Error Like `TypeError`, you can be sure that you are trying to assign a variable of one type onto another type. Well but there is no assignments? Its an indirect assignment to the print concatenation. What you committed to the print is that, you would be supplying 3 parameters out of which first two would be `Integers(%d)` and the last a `string(%d)`. But you ended up supplying 3 `Integers` (`s+1`, `p+1`, `len(sentence)`,`phrase`) which is inconsistent with your print format specifier. Either you drop the third parameter (`len(sentence)`) like

   ```
   print('sentence #%d:, phrase #%d: %s' %(s+1,p+1,phrase))
   ```

   or add one more Format Specifier to the print statement

   ```
   print('sentence #%d:, phrase #%d:, length #%d, %s' %(s+1,p+1,len(sentence),phrase))
   ```

Assuming you want the former want, that leaver us to

```
for s, sentence in enumerate(text.split('.')):
     for p, phrase in enumerate(text.split(',')):
         print('sentence #%d:, phrase #%d:, length #%d, %s' %(s+1,p+1,len(sentence),phrase))
```

Comment: Thank a lot all, i managed to cook the proper discplay order with the insight provided.

Comment: @Abhijit I prefer S.Lott style for answering homework questions. See [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
'sentence #%d:\nphrase #%d: %d %s\n' %(s+1,p+1,len(sentence),phrase)
```

And in the inner loop, you certainly want to split **sentence**, not **text** again

Answer (score 2):

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Is a hint.

Your loops are fine.

```
'sentence #%d:','phrase #%d: %s' %(s+1,p+1,len(sentence),phrase)
```

is wrong.

Count the `%d` and `%s` conversion specifications.  Count the values after the `%` operator/

The numbers aren't the same, are they?  That's a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sen = [words[1] for words in enumerate(text.split(". "))]
>>> for each in sen: each.split(", ")
['what time of the day is it']
["i'm heading out to the ball park", 'with the kids', 'on this nice evening']
['are you willing to join me', 'on the walk to the park', 'tonight.']
```

It's up to you to transform this unassigned output to your liking.